# pause c++ programs at the end, after compiling

Tags: c++

When I compile a program and run the exe file it automatically closes. Is there any way to avoid it? I know you can put `system("pause")` but I heard that it is recommended not to use it, or you can put in a `cin` at the end and wait for the user press something before closing. But is there any "real" official way to make the program stop?

Comment: Run it from a command prompt console :)

Comment: that would work for me, but if I give the exe file to someone to run, I dont want them to use the command prompt

Comment: You can give them a batch file that has the `pause` command at the end.  That way, you're avoiding using `system("pause")` in your code and if someone does want to run it from the command prompt, they can.

Comment: Then you're only way really is to have a std::cout << "Press enter to exit" and using std::cin.ignore() because you won't need that data anyways.

Comment: @FJam, If it's a console program, it's probably meant to be run from the console. Otherwise, they'll probably expect a GUI of some sort.

Comment: how do i make a GUI in c++?

Comment: @FJam, That is a very broad question. You have to pick a framework (or go the stupid route like I do and make something from scratch) and know what you want on it. If you're serious about distributing your programs in a way that they're usable, I would suggest looking into how. I personally much prefer C# for GUI things I make. The drag and drop editor works great for quickly making a customized GUI with fairly clean code, and there are other options for making it look more professional or highly customized.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Visual Studio? if yes and its a version before 2010 then CTRL+F5 will do the trick

if its a version after....

this might help

[http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540969/missing-press-any-key-to-continue-when-lauching-with-ctrl-f5](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/540969/missing-press-any-key-to-continue-when-lauching-with-ctrl-f5/)

Comment: then i am sorry...as my answer doesnt apply at all to your question... it would have helped to include your developing environment in the question though....

Comment: CodeBlocks will add the pause when being run from the IDE in Windows. I think the question was more for the executable, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your program does, what you want it to do.
It means, for 'C++', terminating, when there is no more instructions to run.

You have plenty of methods to stop your program (waiting for some signal, receiving data from socket, ...). Reading from `stdin` is probably the easiest way.

`system("pause")` is not recommended because it just calls system function `Pause` and in some environments there could be no such function.

Comment: Or worse, a function that does something terrible.

Answer (score 0):

If you "Start Without Debugging" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, then the after the program exits the console window remains open and a `Press any key to continue . . .` message is displayed until you press any button. That's the best solution, since it doesn't require any code modification, while if you debug, you can set a breakpoint anywhere you want.

Works with all version of Visual Studio, pretty standard thing.

Answer (score -1):

Windows solution for [visual studio compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) only:

```
fflush(stdin);
getchar()
```

Comment: Since when can you flush stdin?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews According to msdn: fflush on input stream is an extension to the C standard